# Does gets() ignore '\0'?

Tags: c, gcc, buffer-overflow

I am learning about buffer overrun with this source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char buf[16];
    gets(buf);
    printf("buf @ %8p\n", (void*)&buf);
    return 0;
}
```

I try to write `Null` character ('\0') to buf variable.

First, in `gdb`, I set the breakpoint at line 6, after the `gets()` function and run it with `r <<< $(python -c 'print "\0"*11 + "AAAA"')`

When I explore the stack, I realize it only write "AAAA" to `buf`. What happens?

```
(gdb) x/16xw &buf
0xffffcf80: 0x41414141  0xffffd000  0xffffd04c  0x080484a1
0xffffcf90: 0xf7fb43dc  0xffffcfb0  0x00000000  0xf7e1a637
0xffffcfa0: 0xf7fb4000  0xf7fb4000  0x00000000  0xf7e1a637
0xffffcfb0: 0x00000001  0xffffd044  0xffffd04c  0x00000000
```

But, when I run the program with `r <<< $(python -c 'print "\1"*11 + "AAAA"')`, the `buf` will be:

```
(gdb) x/16xw &buf
0xffffcf80: 0x01010101  0x01010101  0x41010101  0x00414141
0xffffcf90: 0xf7fb43dc  0xffffcfb0  0x00000000  0xf7e1a637
0xffffcfa0: 0xf7fb4000  0xf7fb4000  0x00000000  0xf7e1a637
0xffffcfb0: 0x00000001  0xffffd044  0xffffd04c  0x00000000
```

> So the `gets()` function will not receive the `Null` character or the `stdin` will ignore it ?

P/S: I built it with `gcc -m32 -fno-stack-protector -g stack.c -o stack` on gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609.

---

**Update**: After some suggestions, I try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char buf[16];
    gets(buf);
    printf("buf @ %8p\n", (void*)&buf);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) // this is for loop all the buf
    {
        printf("%02x ", buf[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works with '\0'

```
$ gcc -g j_stack.c -o j_stack
$ python -c 'print "AAAA" + "\0"*6 + "AAAA"'| ./j_stack 
buf @ 0xffffcfbc
41 41 41 41 00 00 00 00 00 00 41 41 41 41 00 ffffffff
```

> But how do I provide input which contains `'\0'` to `buf` in `gdb` program

Comment: Minor tip: it would be easier to read this output if you'd initialised `buf` to all 0xFFs or something like that

Comment: The `gets` and `fgets` functions to not treat `'\0'` specially.  They can read null characters just fine.  I used your program to read the string `"ab\0c\n"` and it worked as I expected.

Comment: I think this is due to your use of "here strings" to provide input (the `<<<`). It's a very convoluted way of passing input to your program, don't you think? Take gdb out of the equation and just use a bog-standard pipe from shell; you should then see it working. Let us know if this is true and therefore answer-worthy.

Comment: Sorry about that... My memory was substituting `\0` for `\n`.  Answer deleted.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Run: `od -c <<< $(python -c 'print "\0"*11 + "AAAA"')`; the output I get is four A's and a newline.  As diagnosed, the problem is in the Bash heredoc processing, not your program or `gets()`.  Of course, except for testing overflows, you should know that [`gets()` is too dangerous to be used — ever!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/).  (You could still use `fgets()`; you'd simply write `fgets(buf, 4096, stdin);`, lying through your teeth about the size of `buf`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, it doesn't.**

This behaviour has nothing to do with `gets()`, or with Python strings; it's due to the way you're providing input to your program, using a subshell and the Bash "herestring" syntax (which [performs some manipulations on whatever you give it](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html), apparently including dropping null bytes):

```
# python -c 'print "\0"*11 + "AAAA"' | wc -c
16
# python -c 'print "\0"*11 + "AAAA"' | hexdump
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 4100 4141 0a41
0000010

# cat <<< $(python -c 'print "\0"*11 + "AAAA"') | wc -c
5
# hexdump <<< $(python -c 'print "\0"*11 + "AAAA"')
0000000 4141 4141 000a
0000005

# echo $(python -c 'print "\0"*11 + "AAAA"') | wc -c
5
```

If you run your program with a simple pipe, you should see the results you expect:

```
python -c 'print "\0"*11 + "AAAA"' | ./myProgram
```

Comment: Thanks. So how do I provide input to the program in `gdb`?

Comment: Thank you. I think I should write a input file every time I run the program because I cannot use here string in `gdb`. :(

Answer (score 2):

No, `gets` does not ignore `'\0'`.

I changed your program to include

```
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++) printf("%02x", buf[i]);
printf("\n");
```

after calling `gets`.  I ran the program on the input

```
abc\n
```

and saw

```
61626300000000000000000000000000
```

as I expected.  I then ran the program on the input

```
ab\0c\n
```

and saw

```
61620063000000000000000000000000
```

which was also what I expected.

---

P.S. I'm not sure why you saw the behavior you did, but I confess I'm not sure what you're doing with `<<<` and those python fragments.  Me, I used

```
echo abc | a.out
```

and

```
echo 616200630a | unhex | a.out
```

where `unhex` is a little program I have in my bin directory for, well, doing the obvious.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you mentioned which compiler and OS you used. The behavior noted in the question might be specific to one setup.

Comment: I used clang under MacOS.  But I don't believe the behavior is system-specific.  `gets` and `fgets` are not documented as treating `'\0'` specially, and I have never encountered an implementation that did.

Comment: I don't think it *should* be system specific, but I don't see anything obvious in the question that would invalidate their observation.